# Confusing edit behavior: Is it a bug or a feature?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I sometimes bump into questions which have an `(1)` next to the edit link. If I click on it I am presented with the review screen.

I can either click accept or reject but whatever I do the suggested edit still needs some more accepts to pass.

If there is no suggested edit however I can edit a question without the need of reviewing.

So my question is that this behavior is a bug or a feature?

Sometimes I read questions and they have formatting issues, bad grammar etc... and I click on `edit` and correct the problem(s). But in case of a suggested edit this feature does not work.

*Note: I have sufficient privileges to edit a post.*

Comment: Why don't you just click improve?

Comment: I was not aware of that feature I think.

Comment: It you made an edit before the suggested edit was approved/rejected it could cause a conflict between the two; they're both branches rather that being a single line of edits

Comment: @Adam if you see there are still things to fix just click Improve in the dialog and you'll be able to edit as you wish, causing the suggested edit to get approved (or rejected if you untick "this edit is helpful" box) behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3):

That is the intended behavior.